# Why does Python not connect to my class attribute?

Tags: python, class

I am trying to make a game similar to a MMORPG but is single player. I am trying to put the Player class on one script, the MaelstromPlayer, and it's child class MaelstromMove to connect to it using another script because I am adding the MaelstromBattle and MaelstromInv classes soon.

The problem is that I could not access, not to mention adjust, the MaelstromPlayer class attributes. I wonder what caused this problem and how to solve it, or even if this is possible.

In case you were wondering, I got the method of "Distributing A Class Across Multiple Files" from this website https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-January/618880.html .

This is my code for MaelstromPlayer, the file where I store the parent class.

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.place = int("001")
        self.name = input("What name do you want?")
        self.knownplaces={}
        self.knownplaces[int("001")]="Ruby City"
        self.knownplaces[int("002")]="Ruby Inn"
        self.knownplaces[int("003")]="Ruby Forests"
        self.knownplaces[int("004")]="Ruby Countryside"
        self.knownplaces[int("005")]="Witch Hideout"
        self.mode="moving"
    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.movepossible
```

This is my code for MaelstromMove, where I store the child class of PlayerMove.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('F:\Maelstrom\Python\MaelstromPlayer.py')
from MaelstromPlayer import Player

class PlayerMoving(Player):
    def __init__(Player):
        print('Welcome')
    def movepossible(Player,position):
        #001--Ruby City
        #002--Ruby Inn
        #003--Ruby Forests
        #004--Ruby Countryside
        #005--Witch Hideout
        if position==int("001"):
            possible=[int("002"),int("003")]
            return possible
        elif position==int("002"):
            possible=[int("001")]
            return possible
        elif position==int("003"):
            possible=[int("001"),int("004")]
            return possible
        elif position==int("004"):
            possible=[int("001"),int("003"),int("005")]
            return possible
        elif position==int("005"):
            possible=[int("004")]
            return possible
        else:
            return null
    def move(Player,position):
        if Player.mode=="moving":
            position=int(position)
            possiblewords=[]
            print('Choose between paths:')
            possible = Player.movepossible(position)
            for m in range(0,len(possible),1):
                possiblewords.append(Places.knownplaces[possible[m]])
            for n in range(0,len(possiblewords),1):
                print(str(n+1)+':'+str(possiblewords[n]))

            choice=input('Make your choice...')
                #choice=int(choice)
            if choice == '':
                choice = int('9999999999')
            if int(choice) <= len(possiblewords):
                Player.place=possible[int(choice)-int('1')]
            print("\n")
            print("\n")
    def showposition(Player):
        print('You are at '+Player.knownplaces[int(Player.place)])

test = Player()
while True:
    place = test.place
    test.move(place)
    test.showposition()
```

The sys.path method is from here: http://www.daveoncode.com/2017/03/07/how-to-solve-python-modulenotfound-no-module-named-import-error/ .

Please help, preferably with a code sample, thank you.

Comment: fix your indentation. Also, it doesn't make sense to have the `move` as a class if it's an action of your player... which means it should be a method of such class.

Comment: Why `int("001")` and not just `1`?

Comment: Sorry, the indentation is difficult in Stack Overflow, also, the class makes it easier to put on the web for multiplayer, which I will do later. The int("001") is just my habits, and 001 is for more areas.

Comment: In python we use `self` as the first argument of a method call, not the class name. What if you wanted to call a static method of that class? Also you don't need a single one of those `int` calls. It may be a habit but you should aim to get rid of your bad habits as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I will try, also, I thought that to access the Player class I had to add it in, also, I thought that since I don't need any self calls I don't need it as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you never call the the `PlayerMoving` class (for your test at the bottom), just the `Player` class. Also in the `PlayerMoving` class you override the `Player` class' `__init__` method. To make sure the `Player.__init__` is still called, do something like this:

```
class PlayerMoving(Player):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Welcome')
        super().__init__()
```

---

Some additional problems:

- don't use `int("001")`, it's inefficient, pointless and just bad practice.
- For creating your `dict` do `self.knownplaces = {1: "Ruby City", 2: "Ruby Inn", ...}  # etc`
- `null` isn't defined in python, perhaps you mean `None` but you'll automatically `return None` if you don't return anything else.
- Your `while` loop will never end. Put a `break` clause in or something.
- Don't use `Player` as the first method argument. Use `self` like you'll find in every python class example ever [1](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)[2](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Classes_and_Objects)[3](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Classes#Creating_a_Class)[4](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/class#define)[5](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Classes.html#defining-and-using-a-class).

Finally, have you noticed that that entire thread from https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-January/618880.html is about how you should **never** do this?

Comment: How can I adjust the attributes and arguments in the Player class?

Comment: By doing something like `def f(self): self.knownplaces[1] = 'new place'` like normal. I get the feeling you're getting ahead of yourself. You're trying relatively complex things like inheritance and you haven't got the basics down yet.